# Настройка webstorm и node js

Tags: node.js, webstorm

Пытаюсь расшарить webstorm на работу с node js.Установил node u npm через "sudo apt-get install nodejs/npm",проверяю в консоле "nodejs -v"=v8.10.0, "npm -v"=v3.5.2; В настройках webstorm пути вроде бы рабочие[image: введите сюда описание изображения].
Однако,при создании проекта вылезает ошибка:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите пожалуйста,что я делаю не так

Comment: Попробуйте поставить глобально пакет `express-generator`, может его не хватает.

Comment: Прошу прощения, я новичок в линукс. Это нужно сделать так "npm install -g express-generator"?

Answer (score 1):

[WEB-34814](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-34814) исправлена в webStorm 2018.3 (должен выйти на следующей неделе). Для предыдущих версий единственное решение - настройка NodeSource binary distributions репозитория (https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions).

*Express* приложение можно попробовать создать в командной строке, используя [express-generator](https://github.com/expressjs/generator):

- `npm install -g express-generator`
- `express [options] myApp && cd myApp`
- `npm i`
- открыть директорию `myApp` в WebStorm через **File | Open**